# Splitting by \n character doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a result from a server where items are separated with new lines, so I do a:

```
split('\n');
split('\\n');
```

It doesn't work! the `\` disappears while debugging on Chrome (I see split('n')).

How to make it work?

Sample data (copy from debugger of chrome):

"יופי וקוסמטיקה|10↵בידור ותרבות|9↵לילד ולתינוק|3↵תיירות|4↵תכשיטים|5"

Comment: And? Your question? The rest of the code? The string?

Comment: provide a sample string that is being sent from the server. Also the code snippet that you have written to split the string

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the result has the literal characters `"\n"` in it, you need to escape your `\`.

```
split('\\n');
```

Another possibility is that you have `\r\n` sequences in the string. If so, do this:

```
split('\r\n');
```

...although the `.split('\n')` should still work.

Or if it is sending them with just `\r` sequences, you'd do:

```
split('\r');
```

If you're not sure, do this:

```
split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
```

Comment: OP said items were separated by newlines.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Yes that's true, but OP also said that `.split('\n')` isn't working to split the string. So it seems possible that by new lines, he means he can see `\n` characters in the string.

Comment: /\r\n|\n|\r/  should be replaced with  /\\r\\n|\\n|\\r/

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with `split("\n")` and it is working.

[The choice of double or single quotes](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4724) will make a difference in the way that Ruby treats the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a page that runs under template engine, it removed the "`\`" from the "`\n`".

Answer (score 0):

if you have '↵' character in your paragraph,

Firstly you must replace '↵' character to '\n' then

and if you have web project

you must use 'white-space: pre-line' in your css code.

I have some problem when I get paragraph from database paragraph coming with '↵' 
character and it not add new line in paragraph I used this solution for this problem.