# Can't split an string to an array with \n

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data with new lines (\n). I need to split it to an array to show it in a list.

```
      $scope.proposal = actionProposal;
      var description = actionProposal.ap_description;
      console.log(description.split('#')); //Works
      console.log(description.split('\n')); //Not working
```

I tried it manually here:

http://jsbin.com/yakosavediye/1/

There it works. But not in angular.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here is the full code:

```
$scope.openDetailModal = function(ap_id){
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: './template/modal/detail-view.html',
        resolve:{
          actionProposal: function(SingleEnergyActionProposalLoader){
            return new SingleEnergyActionProposalLoader(ap_id);
          }
        },
        controller:function($scope, $modalInstance, actionProposal){
          $scope.proposal = actionProposal;

          var description = actionProposal.ap_description;
          var desc = description.split('\n');
          console.log(desc);

          $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };
        }
      });
    };
```

If I replace my resolve with a handwritten object, then it works. So it has something to do with the loader. I also trid to do a angular.toJson (which cleans the object) and then parse it back. No effect.

**Update 2**
Here's my loader

```
.factory('EnergyActionProposal', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/actionproposals/:ap_id', {'ap_id': '@ap_id'});
  })
  .factory('SingleEnergyActionProposalLoader', function(EnergyActionProposal, $q){
    return function(ap_id){
      var delay = $q.defer();
      EnergyActionProposal.get({ap_id: ap_id}, function(energyActionProposal) {
        delay.resolve(energyActionProposal);
      }, function () {
        delay.reject('Unable to fetch energy action proposal');
      });
      return delay.promise;
    };
  });
```

Comment: just probing a thought, but does any of your split logic require JQuery? If so, Angular only includes some JQuery so maybe including the JQuery library would help if the functions are the same and one simply doesnt work in only Angular.

Comment: @Austin that makes no sense at all . jQuery doesn't have string manipulation methods and has no bearing on the question

Comment: create a demo using angular that shows where it's not working. Your simple logging methods don't tell us much

Comment: @charlietfl Was just throwing it out there if the only issue was simple javascript to angularJS.

Comment: no way for us to know, you have been chasing this from the bottom, go back to source of `SingleEnergyActionProposalLoader`. Maybe it doesn't even have `\n` in source

Comment: @charlietfl I added the loader to my question. Ofcourse the \n is in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend replacing the newlines with another character `#` or `|` and then doing your split: `desc = description.replace(/\n/,'#');
desc.split('#');`

Comment: I edited it. You have to save the output of `.replace()` to a var. Did you do that?

Comment: Yeha. No effect. Same issue as in split. Can do it with any sign but not with \n.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var test = 'Avstängning av 205-LB1 under helger.\n# Lågflödesdrift för 205-LB5 natt och helger.\n# Anpass drift högfart för 205-LB7 till verksamhetstid.\n# Natt & helgavstängning för 255-LB1.\n# St';

t = test.replace(/\n/,'#');

console.log(t);
```

http://jsbin.com/kifawuvapewo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping \n?

```
description.split('\\n')
```

[Splitting by \n character doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377148/splitting-by-n-character-doesnt-seem-to-work)